# Ruby on Rails - Check where assets (.js) is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im building a application where I give my clients a `.js` file so they can include into `<head></head>` and that `.js` file is providing some functions to my clients website.

Basically the `.js` file is the path to `show.js.erb` view. I am looking for protecting my code and looking for a way so clients/users can't just load the `http://localhost:3000/js_files/2.js` path on their browser and see the code.

Every client has different ID (`.js` path) and different website and I can detect that from my `db`. Is there a way so I see if the file/path is loading from my clients website and if **Yes** load/show the `js` code, otherwise not showing anything.

In other words, a way to check if file is loaded on for ex: mydomain.com or if they just copy the path into their browser.

I have read about **obfuscate**, but its not useful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.base_url` and getting users domain name from database.

**request.base_url helper:**

Basically `request.base_url`, takes only the domain name and removed all other parts.

*ex:* `http://domain.com/q/45/rails` **=>** `domain.com`

*Here is my code:*

```
<% if request.base_url == @domain.website %>
// JS CODE
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to check if your clients copied the js file on their assets or if they are using your domain on the script SRC attribute.

You think something like this may work?

- Add a XHR get/post to your domain on your JS
- Your domain receives the request and process the referer of the XHR (you can check on your controller on rails through `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]`)